# ¿Cómo puedo manejar distintos elementos en Javascript que poseen distintas características cada uno y poder accesar a ellos de manera adecuada?

Tags: javascript, array, undefined

Tengo unos servicios de streaming y los pusheo a un array. Hay servicios de un solo precio y otros de varios precios, y los que no tienen mas de 1 o 2 planes arroja precios undefined, evidentemente porque no lo tienen, pero la operación para esos servicios los arroja igual... Allí no se como se puede omitir eso sin tener que crear un array para los servicios que tienen 3 planes, otro para los que tienen 2 planes, y otros para los que tienen 1 solo.

```
class Streaming {
    constructor (nombre, precioBasico, precioStandard, precioPremium) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precioBasico = precioBasico;
    this.precioStandard = precioStandard;
    this.precioPremium = precioPremium;
    }

    // Declaro la funcion 
    sumaImpuestoDigital () {
        this.precioBasico = this.precioBasico * 0.64;
        this.precioStandard = this.precioStandard * 0.64;
        this.precioPremium = this.precioPremium * 0.64;
    }
}

const serviciosStreaming =[]


// Declaro los objetos, en este caso servicios de Streaming
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Netflix", "279", "459", "669"))
// netflix.descriptionPremium();

// let spotify = new Streaming("Spotify", 199, 279, 359);
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Spotify", "199", "279", "359"));
// spotify.descriptionPremium();

// let hboMax = new Streaming("HBO Max", 218.90, 322.56);
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("HBO Max", "218.90", "322.56"));
// hboMax.descriptionStandard();

// let disney = new Streaming("Disney", 385, 995);
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Disney", "385", "995"));
// disney.descriptionStandard();

// let starPlus = new Streaming("Star Plus", 880, 995);
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Star Plus", "880", "995"));
// starPlus.descriptionStandard();

// let paramountPlus = new Streaming("Paramount Plus", 181.21);  
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Paramount Plus", "181.21"));
// paramountPlus.descriptionBasico();

// let amazonPrime = new Streaming("Amazon Prime", 319);
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Amazon Prime", "319"));
// amazonPrime.descriptionBasico();

for (let i = 0; i < serviciosStreaming.length; i++) {
    serviciosStreaming[i].sumaImpuestoDigital();
}
```

Comment: Cuál es la finalidad de `sumaImpuestoDigital()` puedo ver que esa función no devuelve nada, sino que modifica el estado del objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estoy seguro de entender completamente lo que buscas, pero supongo que se soluciona poniendo valores por defecto en el constructor. Además, si quieres que una propiedad no este presente en los objetos que la tendrán `null` o `undefined` puedes poner un condicional.

```js
class Streaming {
    constructor (nombre, precioBasico = null, precioStandard = null, precioPremium = null ) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    precioBasico && (this.precioBasico = precioBasico);
    precioStandard && (this.precioStandard = precioStandard);
    precioPremium && (this.precioPremium = precioPremium);
    }

    // Declaro la funcion 
    sumaImpuestoDigital () {
        this.precioBasico && (this.precioBasico *=  0.64);
        this.precioStandard && (this.precioStandard *= 0.64);
        this.precioPremium && (this.precioPremium *= 0.64);
    }
}

const serviciosStreaming =[]


serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Netflix", "279", "459", "669"))
serviciosStreaming.push(new Streaming("Amazon Prime", "319"));

for (let i = 0; i < serviciosStreaming.length; i++) {
    serviciosStreaming[i].sumaImpuestoDigital();
}

console.log(serviciosStreaming);
```